# float型を扱う際に問題点があります。

Tags: c++

atcoderをやっていたのですが、このcinに1.3と1.2を入力すると、望まない挙動(error出力)が起きます。キャストなどいろいろ試してみたのですが、原因が分かりません。わかる方いましたら、どうかお願いします。

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float xy;
    cin>>xy;
    float temp=(xy-(int)xy)*10;
    if((temp>=0)&&(temp<=2)){
        cout<<temp<<"-";
    }
    else if((temp>=3)&&(temp<=6)){
        cout<<temp;

    }
    else if ((temp>=7)&&(temp<=9)){
        cout<<temp<<"+";
    }
    else 
    cout<<"error";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージも質問に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: @cubick 「望まない挙動(error出力)」とは`cout<<"error";`行が実行され`error`という文字列が表示されることを説明していると思われます。エラーメッセージは書かれている通り`error`のはずです。

Comment: FYI: 「[浮動小数点数は実数ではない](https://ja.wikisource.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E%E3%81%8C%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D97%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8/%E6%B5%AE%E5%8B%95%E5%B0%8F%E6%95%B0%E7%82%B9%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AF%E5%AE%9F%E6%95%B0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)」にある通り、コンピュータが扱える浮動小数点数型（`float`型など）は数学でいう実数(Real number)とは異なる振る舞いとなります。

Answer (score 0):

変数`temp`は`float`型ですので、机上での計算結果が2.0だったとしてもコンピュータ内の表現では整数の2と一致しないこともあります。
ですので範囲指定の際に

```
if((temp>=0)&&(temp<=2)){
    cout<<temp<<"-";
}
else if((temp>=3)&&(temp<=6)){
```

では2から3の間にある値は全てすり抜けてしまいます。

```
else if((temp>2)&&(temp<=6)){
```

としてみてください。

Comment: 入力1.2に対しては最初のif条件がtrueになるべきという点が改善されていないのでは。
仕様がはっきりしないので推測ですが。

Comment: おっしゃる通りですね、ちょっと雑な回答でした。仕様次第では計算結果を四捨五入するとかの処理も必要になってきますね。

Answer (score 0):

最大精度を使用して浮動小数点値を出力し、何が得られるかを確認してください。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

int main () {
    using namespace std;
    
    cout << setprecision(numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10);
    
    const float xy = 1.3f;
    cout << ((xy - (int)xy) * 10) << endl;
}
```

最新のアーキテクチャのほとんどは、浮動小数点型を表すために[IEEE-754](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)標準を使用しています。

上記のコードを実行すると、アーキテクチャがIEEE-754をサポートしている場合、出力は次のようになります。

```
// プログラム出力
2.99999952
```

ご覧のとおり、この値は2〜3であるため、条件 `(temp >= 3) && (temp <= 6)`は `false`になります。

しかし、これには修正方法があります。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    float xy;
    cin >> xy;

    // 以下では、浮動小数点数が1つの小数で構成されていることを確認します。
    if (floor(xy * 10) == xy * 10) {
        // roundf(...)」は、精度誤差をなくすために、以下の浮動小数点値を丸めるのに使われます。
        float temp = roundf((xy - (int)xy) * 10);

        if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 2)
            cout << temp << "-";
        else if (temp >= 3 && temp <= 6)
            cout << temp;
        else if (temp >= 7 && temp <= 9)
            cout << temp << "+";
    }
    else 
        cout << "error";
}
```

上記はプログラム入力 `1.3`に対して正しく機能し、期待通りに`3`を与えます。

Comment: `roundf` を使ってしまうと、例えば `1.39` という入力に対して `4` を返すことになってしまいます(本来は`3.9`)。

Comment: @metropolis コメントありがとうございます。その点も考慮して回答を編集しました。